# KML mapping for ancient India

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm getting started with KML and would like to know how to proceed with some special features of my project.

I am working on a map of India in 500BCE. This raises a number of issues.

1. **Uncertainty.** Many of the places I want to map are uncertain, and can only be specified in approximate terms. Places fall into 3 categories:

   1. known places (like Rajagaha=Rajgir)
   2. uncertain but with uniquely identifiable features (eg. "on the road between Rajagaha and Nalanda")
   3. uncertain and non-unique (such as towns that are specified only as being in a certain region).

   So, how should I approach this? The first category is unproblematic. For the second one I would like to indicate a place, while clearly alerting the user that it is no more than an educated guess. For the third, we can to no better than placing a list of towns (etc.) inside a region. Can this be captured in a useful way in KML?
2. **Multiple Names.** Many of the places have multiple names, whether variant readings in the texts, or translated names in Chinese and so on. Is it possible to record a list of alternative names with the KML data. Of course, only one of these will be displayed, but the others are there for interfacing with other applications. For example, someone's reading a text, they come across a place name in Chinese, and Bingo! they can go to the map, which has the name in Pali.